# FCM Cannot subscribe to topic: 000000005eb68872 with token: (null)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

Hi iam trying to implement google firebase push notification and subscribe to a Topic.

i am able to receive push notification but not subscribing to topic.Error says `Cannot subscribe to topic: 000000005eb68872 with token: (null)` but i have the token generated already.

I am Using IOS 11 and Xcode 9.0

**Pod File**

```
target 'VQ Smart Home' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for VQ Smart Home
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.0.4'
    pod 'Firebase/Database', '4.0.4'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '4.0.4'
    pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'
end
```

AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true



/************************ FireBase Notification ************************************************************************/
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
     print("********* FCM token: \(token ?? "") *************")

    hubId = (isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "hubID")) ?  (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "hubID") as? String)! : "NohubId"
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: hubId)

/************************ FireBase Notification ************************************************************************/

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

// Push Notification Methods
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    print(aps["alert"]  as? String ?? "")
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

**Error Stack**

> ```
> [1022:258833] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003016] Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually,
> ```
>
> call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
>       [1022]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003016] Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns
>   manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
>       ********* FCM token: dLdjXagKJpA:APA91bH500MivUUFRUl-1mgqn7qrzp6lVG2divijtBR9RYBgQu4slIBE8W7FN_3VtM_lbyE7S-xcgK40dzrlw2h4fz0SzDrfyPF90KIrUUqE9qNDwOGGrtOLemV1qC1wcrdL2L4aB1Ro
>
> ---
>
> ```
> [1022:258837] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension
> ```
>
> length is less than sct data length
>       [1022:258810] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
>       [1022:258810] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
>       [1022:258838] [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002010] Cannot subscribe to topic: 000000005eb68872 with token: (null)
>       [1022:258810] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>       ]  [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002010] Cannot subscribe to topic: 000000005eb68872 with token: (null)
>       [1022:258838] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function
>   properly. Learn more at http://
>       ]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function
>   properly. Learn more at http://
>       [1022:258810] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
>       [1022:258810] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
>       [1022:258810] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
>       [1022:258832] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40002000 started
>       ]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40002000 started
>       [1022:258832] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument:
>   -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
>       ]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument:
>   -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
>       [1022:258839] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
>       ]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
>       [1022:258839] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
>       ]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
>       [1022:258833] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>       [1022:258833] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57

can someone help me to fix this tnx..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

I was trying to subscribe Topic in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, but all the require methods and modules are not loaded during this time. so i moved the subscription code inside the **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** now it works fine.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: hubId)
    }
```